# Why JetBrains TFSIntegration plugin not working on Android Studio 1.0

Tags: android-studio, tfsintegrationplatform

I want to start working on android studio 1.0, but i want to integrate my project with TFS server , and i found that the TFSIntegration provided by JetBrains plugin has a problem ??

Can anyone help me ??